# android-maven-plugin: how to merge java resources from aar into apk?

Tags: android, maven, resources, android-maven-plugin, aar

I have an aar lib that contains required java resource files. However, when building the final apk application file, only the classes end up in classes.dex, not the resource files stored along them in classes.jar contained within the .aar lib file.

Any idea how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was obviously that the resources were located below META-INF/. I renamed the directory  and now it works...